# Cannot Import Numpy in Spyder

Tags: numpy, import

For some reason my Spyder code cannot import numpy. I get this error when I try to import numpy:
[image]

I tried uninstalling numpy in the anaconda prompt to reinstall but get this error:
[image]

When I run "pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.23.5," I get this:
[image]

Everything with numpy was working fine before. How do I fix this?